# How does GCC print a stack trace?

Tags: c++, gcc

when gcc/g++ encounters an ICE (internal compiler error), then recent versions of the compiler will print a neat stack trace before exiting.

Questions: What technology is used to implement that? GCC is written in C++, afaik some conservative revision like C++03.

In particular

- GCC does not use Boost.
- GCC does not use external libraries like linunwind or libexcept to all of my knowledge.
- GCC does not necessarily use glibc. For example I can cross-compile GCC on linux for host mingw32, and stack traces work just fine.

---

So before blindly closing this question, please make sure the linked answer does not need any of these libraries.

Comment: What makes you think GCC uses any publicly available library for its stack trace? If anything, I bet those libraries are based on GCC's implementation.

Comment: see https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/bc35ef6543424134df1619909df728a52d6f1f7f/gcc/diagnostic.c#L517 and https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libbacktrace

Comment: @Blindy My 1st question was closed with a pointer to another question that proposed all fancy stuff that GCC doesn't use. All what's needed for GCC are GMP, MPFR, MPC, which have nothing to do with the feature in question.

Comment: @KamilCuk As far as I understand, mingw uses msvcrt and not glibc.

Comment: Have you read the source code to GCC? In particular, the code under the libbacktrace subdirectory?

Comment: @Stephen M. Webb : No, I did not read that more then 5.000.000 lines of highly non-trivial code. Is that library a host library like libiberty or a target library like libasan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As many people mentioned in comments GCC statically links against `libbacktrace` which uses `libgcc` on ELF platforms (e.g. Linux) and custom code on AIX and Windows. Assuming that most people will be interested in Linux, I expand on that one that below.

GCC runtime library (`libgcc`) contains stack unwinding code which is used for C++ exceptions and error reporting. In particular it's used by Glibc ([backtrace(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/backtrace.3.html)), AddressSanitizer and GCC itself.

Internal implementation of unwinding is highly target-dependent. For example on amd64 it uses stack layout metadata stored in `.eh_frame` sections (see https://uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf), on ARM it uses metadata as well (but in different format) and on i386 it manually parses the function prologue instructions (for platform-specific details one can study the relevant unwind files in https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libgcc).

Comment: libgcc is a target library, not a host library. It is used for unwinding of exceptions. This means only target code will use that unwinding, and it is used implicitly during exception handling, maybe also in non-local goto. GCC itself will only be linked against host libraries.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts "libgcc is a target library, not a host library" - sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by this (all programs on my host are linked against libgcc, including gcc executable). "It is used for unwinding of exceptions" - it's used for any stack unwinding, please examine implementations of `backtrace(3)` and Asan's error handling code.

Comment: Your GCC is using libgcc as a *target* library because it was *built* by GCC. If you use a different build compiler than GCC, then GCC will use that compiler's support library. In most situations this will be masked by bootstrap. Hence use a different build compiler and configure with `--disable-bootstrap` and check the resulting compiler. .

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts I've added a note that libbacktrace uses custom unwinders on AIX and Windows.